# EasynetQ autosubscribe throwing error: *System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name'*

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, message-queue, messagebroker, easynetq

**I'm trying to autosubscribe, it is throwing error:**
*System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name'*

**here is my consumer code.**

```
public class MyConsumer: IConsumeAsync<MyMessage>
    {

        public MyConsumer() {
        }

       
        public async Task ConsumeAsync(MyMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        
    }
```

**here is my message code.**

```
[Queue("QueueName", ExchangeName = "ExchangeName")]
    public class MyMessage
    {
        public string? Val1{ get; set; }
    }
```

**this is how i am subscribing.**

```
var bus = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IBus>();
    var bus = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IBus>();
                var subscriber = new AutoSubscriber(bus, "subsId_prefix");
                subscriber.Subscribe(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes());
```

I'm using .net 6 and EasynetQ version 6.0.1.